# How to use a parse table and stack push map in a table driven parser?

Tags: compiler-construction

I'm writing a compiler, using top-down table-driven parsing. I've converted my grammar into LL(1), and it's the following:

```
<START> -> <prog> 

<aParams> -> <expr> <rept-aParams1> 
<aParams> -> EPSILON 

<aParamsTail> -> ',' <expr> 

<addOp> -> '+' 
<addOp> -> '-' 
<addOp> -> 'or' 

<arithExpr> -> <term> <rightrec-arithExpr> 

<arraySize> -> '[' 'intNum' ']' 
<arraySize> -> '[' ']' 

<assignOp> -> '=' 

<assignStat> -> <variable> <assignOp> <expr> 

<classDecl> -> 'class' 'id' <opt-classDecl2> '{' <rept-classDecl4> '}' ';' 

<expr> -> <arithExpr> 
<expr> -> <relExpr> 

<fParams> -> <type> 'id' <rept-fParams2> <rept-fParams3> 
<fParams> -> EPSILON 

<fParamsTail> -> ',' <type> 'id' <rept-fParamsTail3> 

<factor> -> <variable> 
<factor> -> <functionCall> 
<factor> -> 'intNum' 
<factor> -> 'floatNum' 
<factor> -> '(' <arithExpr> ')' 
<factor> -> 'not' <factor> 
<factor> -> <sign> <factor> 

<funcBody> -> <opt-funcBody0> 'do' <rept-funcBody2> 'end' 

<funcDecl> -> 'id' '(' <fParams> ')' ':' <type> ';' 
<funcDecl> -> 'id' '(' <fParams> ')' ':' 'void' ';' 

<funcDef> -> <funcHead> <funcBody> ';' 

<funcHead> -> <opt-funcHead0> 'id' '(' <fParams> ')' ':' <type> 
<funcHead> -> <opt-funcHead0> 'id' '(' <fParams> ')' ':' 'void' 

<functionCall> -> <rept-functionCall0> 'id' '(' <aParams> ')' 

<idnest> -> 'id' <rept-idnest1> '.' 
<idnest> -> 'id' '(' <aParams> ')' '.' 

<indice> -> '[' <arithExpr> ']' 

<memberDecl> -> <funcDecl> 
<memberDecl> -> <varDecl> 

<multOp> -> '*' 
<multOp> -> '/' 
<multOp> -> 'and' 

<opt-classDecl2> -> 'inherits' 'id' <rept-opt-classDecl22> 
<opt-classDecl2> -> EPSILON 

<opt-funcBody0> -> 'local' <rept-opt-funcBody01> 
<opt-funcBody0> -> EPSILON 

<opt-funcHead0> -> 'id' 'sr' 
<opt-funcHead0> -> EPSILON 

<prog> -> <rept-prog0> <rept-prog1> 'main' <funcBody> 

<relExpr> -> <arithExpr> <relOp> <arithExpr> 

<relOp> -> 'eq' 
<relOp> -> 'neq' 
<relOp> -> 'lt' 
<relOp> -> 'gt' 
<relOp> -> 'leq' 
<relOp> -> 'geq' 

<rept-aParams1> -> <aParamsTail> <rept-aParams1> 
<rept-aParams1> -> EPSILON 

<rept-classDecl4> -> <visibility> <memberDecl> <rept-classDecl4> 
<rept-classDecl4> -> EPSILON 

<rept-fParams2> -> <arraySize> <rept-fParams2> 
<rept-fParams2> -> EPSILON 

<rept-fParams3> -> <fParamsTail> <rept-fParams3> 
<rept-fParams3> -> EPSILON 

<rept-fParamsTail3> -> <arraySize> <rept-fParamsTail3> 
<rept-fParamsTail3> -> EPSILON 

<rept-funcBody2> -> <statement> <rept-funcBody2> 
<rept-funcBody2> -> EPSILON 

<rept-functionCall0> -> <idnest> <rept-functionCall0> 
<rept-functionCall0> -> EPSILON 

<rept-idnest1> -> <indice> <rept-idnest1> 
<rept-idnest1> -> EPSILON 

<rept-opt-classDecl22> -> ',' 'id' <rept-opt-classDecl22> 
<rept-opt-classDecl22> -> EPSILON 

<rept-opt-funcBody01> -> <varDecl> <rept-opt-funcBody01> 
<rept-opt-funcBody01> -> EPSILON 

<rept-prog0> -> <classDecl> <rept-prog0> 
<rept-prog0> -> EPSILON 

<rept-prog1> -> <funcDef> <rept-prog1> 
<rept-prog1> -> EPSILON 

<rept-statBlock1> -> <statement> <rept-statBlock1> 
<rept-statBlock1> -> EPSILON 

<rept-varDecl2> -> <arraySize> <rept-varDecl2> 
<rept-varDecl2> -> EPSILON 

<rept-variable0> -> <idnest> <rept-variable0> 
<rept-variable0> -> EPSILON 

<rept-variable2> -> <indice> <rept-variable2> 
<rept-variable2> -> EPSILON 

<rightrec-arithExpr> -> EPSILON 
<rightrec-arithExpr> -> <addOp> <term> <rightrec-arithExpr> 

<rightrec-term> -> EPSILON 
<rightrec-term> -> <multOp> <factor> <rightrec-term> 

<sign> -> '+' 
<sign> -> '-' 

<statBlock> -> 'do' <rept-statBlock1> 'end' 
<statBlock> -> <statement> 
<statBlock> -> EPSILON 

<statement> -> <assignStat> ';' 
<statement> -> 'if' '(' <relExpr> ')' 'then' <statBlock> 'else' <statBlock> ';' 
<statement> -> 'while' '(' <relExpr> ')' <statBlock> ';' 
<statement> -> 'read' '(' <variable> ')' ';' 
<statement> -> 'write' '(' <expr> ')' ';' 
<statement> -> 'return' '(' <expr> ')' ';' 
<statement> -> <functionCall> ';' 

<term> -> <factor> <rightrec-term> 

<type> -> 'integer' 
<type> -> 'float' 
<type> -> 'id' 

<varDecl> -> <type> 'id' <rept-varDecl2> ';' 

<variable> -> <rept-variable0> 'id' <rept-variable2> 

<visibility> -> 'public' 
<visibility> -> 'private'
```

Using the tool [here](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/ll-1-parser-generator), I've generated a parse table and stack push map, which are the following:

Parse Table:

```
[[0,"','","'+'","'-'","'or'","'['","'intNum'","']'","'='","'class'","'id'","'{'","'}'","';'","'floatNum'","'('","')'","'not'","'do'","'end'","':'","'void'","'.'","'*'","'/'","'and'","'inherits'","'local'","'sr'","'main'","'eq'","'neq'","'lt'","'gt'","'leq'","'geq'","'if'","'then'","'else'","'while'","'read'","'write'","'return'","'integer'","'float'","'public'","'private'","$"],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,1,1,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,1,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111],[0,112,2,2,112,112,2,112,112,112,2,112,112,112,2,2,3,2,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,4,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,5,6,7,112,111,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,111,111,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,111,8,8,112,112,8,111,112,112,8,112,112,111,8,8,111,8,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,111,111,111,111,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,111,112,112,112,10,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,111,111,112,112,111,112,11,112,111,112,112,112,111,111,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,12,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,13,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,111,15,15,112,112,15,112,112,112,15,112,112,111,15,15,111,15,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,16,112,112,112,112,112,17,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,16,16,112,112,112],[0,18,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,111,25,25,111,112,21,111,112,112,20,112,112,111,22,23,111,24,112,112,112,112,112,111,111,111,112,112,112,112,111,111,111,111,111,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,26,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,26,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,28,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,111,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,29,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,31,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,111,111,111,111,112,112,111,112,112,32,112,112,111,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,111,111,112,112,112,112,111,111,111,111,111,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,34,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,111,111,111,111,35,112,111,111,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,111,111,111,111,112,112,112,112,111,111,111,111,111,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,37,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,37,37,111,111,112],[0,112,111,111,112,112,111,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,111,111,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,38,39,40,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,42,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,41,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,44,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,43,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,46,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,47,47,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,47,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111],[0,111,48,48,112,112,48,112,112,112,48,112,112,111,48,48,111,48,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,111,111,112,112,111,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,111,111,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,49,50,51,52,53,54,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,55,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,56,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,58,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,57,57,112],[0,60,112,112,112,59,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,60,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,61,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,62,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,64,112,112,112,63,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,64,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,65,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,66,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,65,112,112,65,65,65,65,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,68,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,69,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,70,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,71,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,72,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,73,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,74,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,73,73,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,75,76,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,76,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,77,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,78,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,79,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,80,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,79,112,112,79,79,79,79,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,81,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,82,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,84,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,86,86,86,86,85,112,86,86,112,112,112,112,86,112,112,86,112,112,112,112,112,112,86,86,86,112,112,112,112,86,86,86,86,86,86,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,87,88,88,88,112,112,87,112,112,112,112,112,87,112,112,87,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,87,87,87,87,87,87,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,89,89,89,89,112,112,89,112,112,112,112,112,89,112,112,89,112,112,112,112,112,112,90,90,90,112,112,112,112,89,89,89,89,89,89,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,91,92,112,112,111,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,111,111,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,94,112,112,95,112,112,112,112,93,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,94,112,95,94,94,94,94,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,102,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,97,112,111,98,99,100,101,112,112,112,112,112],[0,111,103,103,111,112,103,111,112,112,103,112,112,111,103,103,111,103,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,111,111,111,111,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,106,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,104,105,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,107,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,107,107,111,111,112],[0,111,111,111,111,112,112,111,111,112,108,112,112,111,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,111,111,112,112,112,112,111,111,111,111,111,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112],[0,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112,111,111,109,110,112]]
```

Push map:

```
{"1":[26],"2":[29,10],"4":[10,-1],"5":[-2],"6":[-3],"7":[-4],"8":[45,50],"9":[-7,-6,-5],"10":[-7,-5],"11":[-8],"12":[10,7,53],"13":[-13,-12,30,-11,23,-10,-9],"14":[5],"15":[27],"16":[32,31,-10,51],"18":[33,-10,51,-1],"19":[53],"20":[18],"21":[-6],"22":[-14],"23":[-16,5,-15],"24":[13,-17],"25":[13,47],"26":[-19,34,-18,24],"27":[-13,51,-20,-16,11,-15,-10],"28":[-13,-21,-20,-16,11,-15,-10],"29":[-13,14,17],"30":[51,-20,-16,11,-15,-10,25],"31":[-21,-20,-16,11,-15,-10,25],"32":[-16,2,-15,-10,35],"33":[-22,36,-10],"34":[-22,-16,2,-15,-10],"35":[-7,5,-5],"36":[15],"37":[52],"38":[-23],"39":[-24],"40":[-25],"41":[37,-10,-26],"43":[38,-27],"45":[-28,-10],"47":[14,-29,40,39],"48":[5,28,5],"49":[-30],"50":[-31],"51":[-32],"52":[-33],"53":[-34],"54":[-35],"55":[29,3],"57":[30,21,54],"59":[31,6],"61":[32,12],"63":[33,6],"65":[34,49],"67":[35,19],"69":[36,20],"71":[37,-10,-1],"73":[38,52],"75":[39,9],"77":[40,16],"79":[41,49],"81":[42,6],"83":[43,19],"85":[44,20],"88":[45,50,4],"90":[46,13,22],"91":[-2],"92":[-3],"93":[-19,41,-18],"94":[49],"96":[-13,8],"97":[-13,48,-38,48,-37,-16,27,-15,-36],"98":[-13,48,-16,27,-15,-39],"99":[-13,-16,53,-15,-40],"100":[-13,-16,10,-15,-41],"101":[-13,-16,10,-15,-42],"102":[-13,18],"103":[46,13],"104":[-43],"105":[-44],"106":[-10],"107":[-13,42,-10,51],"108":[44,-10,43],"109":[-45],"110":[-46]}
```

The construction of the parsing table is given as the following:

```
On the LL(1) Parsing Table's Meaning and Construction

    The top row corresponds to the columns for all the potential terminal symbols, augmented with $ to represent the end of the parse.
    The leftmost column and second row are all zero filled, to accomodate the way Fischer and LeBlanc wrote their parser's handling of abs().
    The remaining rows correspond to production rules in the original grammar that you typed in.
    Each entry in that row maps the left-hand-side (LHS) of a production rule onto a line-number. That number is the line in which the LHS had that specific column symbol in its predict set.

    If a terminal is absent from a non-terminal's predict set, an error code is placed in the table. If that terminal is in follow(that non-terminal), the error is a POP error. Else, it's a SCAN error.

    POP error code = # of predict table productions + 1

    SCAN error code = # of predict table productions + 2

In practice, you'd want to tear the top, label row off of the table and stick it in a comment, so that you can make sense of your table. The remaining table can be used as is.
```

Given these, though, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed. I'm just curious what the general algorithm, given the two objects, would be to parse over a stream of tokens and determine it's syntactically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't help you much because, as noted below, LL(1) parse tables generated for that grammar cannot be accurate.

However, for what it's worth, here's my reverse engineering of those tables. It's probable that you could get a deeper understanding of this procedure by reading the [text book referenced by the tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805321667). (***Note:*** link is *not* an endorsement, neither of the book nor of the vendor. I just copied it from the tool.)

The terminal symbols appear in order in the top row of the parse table (the one which the instructions say should be removed for use). So terminal symbol 1 is `','`, symbol 2 is `'+'`, and so on up to symbol 46, which is the `$` conventionally used as an end-of-input marker. (That's different from `'$'`, which would be a literal dollar sign.)

Non-terminal symbols don't appear explicitly (so you can't recover their names from the tables) but they are also numbered in order. There are 54 of them, and each row of the parse table (after the first two) corresponds to a non-terminal symbol.

There are 110 productions, which are listed (with their corresponding index) in the Predict set section of the output from that tool. Each production corresponds to one entry in the "push map", which (since this is Javascript) uses the string conversion of the production number as a key.

The corresponding value in the push map is a list of indices: negative indices refer to terminals and positive indices refer to non-terminals. The index 0 is not used, which is why row 0 of the parse map is unused. From these indices, it is possible to reconstruct the right-hand side of the production, but they are actually used to indicate what to push onto the parse stack at each step in the parse.

The stack contains the list current predictions, with the top element of the stack being the immediate prediction at this point in the parse.

So the algorithm is as follows:

1. Initialise the parser stack to `[1, -46]`, which indicates that the current prediction consists of the right-hand side of the production `<START> -> <prog>` followed by the end-of-input marker `$`.
2. Repeat the following until terminated by an error or by acceptance:

   1. If the top of the stack is negative:

      - If the lookahead token has the corresponding token number (that is, the absolute value of the stack top), then pop the stack and accept the lookahead token. If that token is the end-of-input indicator, then the parse is finished and the input was valid. Otherwise, the new lookahead token is the next input token.
      - If the lookahead token does not correspond with the top of the stack, then the input is incorrect. Report an error and terminate the parse.
   2. If the top of the stack is positive:

      - Retrieve the value `rhs` from `parseTable[stack.top()][lookahead]`. If `rhs` has a value greater than the number of productions (in this case, the values 111 or 112) then the input is incorrect. Report an error and terminate the parse. (The value will tell you whether it was a scan error or a pop error, but that might not make much difference to you. It could be used to improve error reporting.)
      - Pop the parse stack, and push the elements from `pushMap[rhs]` onto the stack, starting at the end. (For example, if `rhs` were 4, you would use the list from `pushMap["4"]`, which is `[10, -1]`. So you would push first `-1` and then `10` onto the parser stack.)
      - For the push-map generated by the hacking-off tool, it appears that there will be no entry in the pushMap for ε right-hand sides. So if `pushMap[rhs]` doesn't exist, you just pop the parse stack; there is nothing to push.

That algorithm does not include any procedure for producing a syntax tree for successful parses. But if you want to do anything more than just decide whether the input is a valid program or not, then you will definitely want to produce some kind of syntax tree.

---

#### Note: The grammar is not LL(1) so the parse tables are wrong.

I don't know how much credibility you should give the tool you are using.

Your grammar is not LL(1), but the tool does not provide any indication of that fact.

A simple example is

```
<arraySize> -> '[' 'intNum' ']' 
<arraySize> -> '[' ']'
```

where the lookahead token `[` does not predict a unique production. That would be easy to fix by left-factoring, but I don't see any evidence that the tool is capable of doing that.

A more serious problem is

```
<expr>      -> <arithExpr> 
<expr>      -> <relExpr> 
<arithExpr> -> <term> <rightrec-arithExpr> 
<relExpr>   -> <arithExpr> <relOp> <arithExpr>
```

Since a `relExpr` can start with `arithExpr`, the two productions for `expr` overlap; it's not possible to predict from an examination of a single lookahead token (or, indeed, any constant number of lookahead tokens) whether the `expr` is a comparison or not. You can't tell until you finish parsing the initial arithmetic expression (which could have an arbitrary length).

If you insist on LL(1), you would need to do something like:

```
<expr> -> <arithExpr> <optional-relExpr-tail>
<optional_relExpr-tail> -> EPSILON
<optional_relExpr-tail> -> <relop> <arithExpr>
```

Moreover, `expr` leads to `factor`, which could be either a `variable` or a `functionCall`, both of which start with `idnest` (which ultimately leads to the terminal `id`). But that's not the whole story either, because you might encounter the sequence `<id> '(' <aParams> ')'` both in `idnest` and in `functionCall`.

Perhaps that tool doesn't intend to tell you that your grammar is not LL(1), but it seems to me like it should not generate tables in that case, since the tables are necessarily misleading. The prediction conflicts mean that the parsing table must prefer one or another competing production, and whichever one it does not prefer cannot appear in a parse, with the result that valid inputs will be rejected.

<opinion>

I believe that it is possible to create an LL(1) grammar for that language, but honestly it does not seem to me to be the best strategy. There are already so many book-keeping non-terminals in the grammar that it verges on the unreadable. If you insist on a top-down parser, use a generator which allows "extended" BNF: repetition and optionality operators on the right-hand side. Alternatively, you can use an LALR(1) generator with a much-simplified grammar, since LALR(1) allows both left-recursion and left-unfactored productions.

</opinion>

Comment: I didn't realize the grammar wasn't in LL(1), it makes sense now why I wasn't able to make much sense of the parsing table/push map when I tried implementing them in my code.

The grammar, as shown, was actually converted through a few tools I have in an attempt to make it LL(1), which is probably why it verges on unreadable. This is the original grammar, before any attempt to convert it. Many of the opt, rept, and rel productions are due to removing the EBNF constructs https://pastebin.com/VAWPbxb5

Comment: If you write a recursive descent parser, then you can directly code the repetition `{{X}}` as a loop, `while lookahead in FIRST(X):` and the optional `[X]` as `if lookahead in FIRST(X):`. In many cases it will turn out to be better to invert the test by testing for the follow token (not FOLLOW(X), but rather the token which follows the repetition/optionality in the RHS where it appears.) But recursive descent is not optimal. For one thing, it suffers from possible stack overflow....

Comment: @agsl: OTOH, if you're going to use a table driven parser, you might as well use an LALR(1) parser. The table-based algorithm is no more complicated, and it handles a much wider range of grammars.

Comment: And it also naturally provides for building a syntax tree because each syntax node is constructed when it's complete, rather than being predicted when it's started. With a bottom-up parser, the actual child nodes are on the stack when the RHS is handled. I honestly don't understand why there is so much resistance to bottom-up parsing.